# Citrix XenServer or VMWare on 32Bit Hardware

Tags: vmware-esx, xenserver

Does anyone know if either XenServer of VMWare have a virtual server version that will run on old 32bit servers? I've got a spare old server that I want to do some testing on with the technologies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Äh - you are aware that NO 32 bit hardware supports virtualization in hardware, so the result - even if you would find software - would SUCK. Like majorly.

Even early 64 bit CPU's lack hardware virtualization.

Retire the old stuff. That is what I do with my old hardware. There simply is no way to run a proper hyper-visor without hardware support in the CPU.

Comment: Uhhhh.... ESX3.x ran just fine on 32-bit CPUs. And without sucking majorly.

Comment: Ah - your definition of not sucking is my definition of crap. Really. WEithout hardware virtualization - which no 32 bit CPU i know of has in the intel world - there is a significant CPU overhead. Virtual Server ALSO worked 32 bit without hardware support. I used it for years. I would not have called that non-sucking performance wise, though. It sucked. NO way to reun anything requiringr real performance on that.

Comment: TomTom is actually quite incorrect.  VMware ESX(i) ran fine on 32 bit hardware.

Answer (score 1):

[ESX 3.x(i) will run on 32-bit hardware](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003661), but will only allow you to run 32-bit guests. Furthermore, you can check the [whitebox hcl](http://www.vm-help.com/esx/esx3.5/Whiteboxes_SATA_Controllers_for_ESX_3.5_3i.htm) for stuff that you have laying around that will make a nice home lab environment. I'd recommend against running it in production.

Answer (score 0):

Xen would only support paravirtualised guests (i.e. Linux). VMware ESX would run everything but it wouldn't be fast. I recommend Xen if you are happy with paravirtualisation and/or don't need to run Windows guests.